# Azure API Management passthrough to backend service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I would like to setup an Azure API Gateway that accepts requests for a backend service and simply passes the requests through to the backend with no modification.  For example:
(-> means it would get routed to)

https://dude.azure-api.net/foo -> https://realapi.mycompany.com/foo

https://dude.azure-api.net/bar -> https://realapi.mycompany.com/bar

etc

I want to use wild cards to set this up so that I don't have to specify every single endpoint in every single API.

This is very, very similar to [Use Azure Api Management as a passthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862461/use-azure-api-management-as-a-passthrough)

however, I have a combination of GET's and POST's so that accepted solution won't work.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create wildcard operation per HTTP method. For sample above you could create two APIs, one with /foo suffix, and another with /bar. Both should have two operations - GET and POST - with "/*" as URI template.

Alternatively if you want complete passthrough - create single API with "/" suffix and two operations - GET and POST - both with "/*" URI template.

Comment: For various reasons, I can't create a wildcard operation for every HTTP method.  So I tried the 2nd method but I keep getting a 500 internal server error.  Still trying to work through that.  I tried replacing the backend with a well known, public REST API, and it seemed to work fine (at least the GET calls did - I have no way to test POST on that API).  So there must be something specific with my own API that is causing the 500 error.  I am using Postman to test it out.  If I put in the real URL, it works fine.  Swap in the Azure URL, and I get the 500 error.

Comment: When you try to test things from Azure Portal, do you see any trace with response?

Answer (score 0):

For complete pass-though, you just need to specify "/" as the **API URL Suffix**

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work for me.  I just get a 404 not found error.  Let's say my backend URL is https://realapi.mycompany.com/ and it has a "GET foo" endpoint defined.  My Azure URL is https://dude.azure-api.net/ .  So calling https://dude.azure-api.net/foo should get routed to https://realapi.mycompany.com/foo but I just get the 404.  If I don't define any operations in Azure, do I have to do something else to the API setup to make this work?

Comment: You have to define operation. Try creating api with empty API suffix and one operation with /* template and GET method.