# Azure APIM route the incoming request based on request URL

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-policy, ibm-api-management, apim

I have a use case to route the request based on incoming url

where in API URL suffix - apples/grapes

**Case 1:**
suppose an incoming request is

https://fruits.com/apples/grapes/rest

then I need to divert the request to backend url say: https://stores.com/a/g

I am able to achieve this by adding **<rewrite-uri template="/"/?** to inbound policy

**Case 2:**

suppose if the incoming request is

https://fruits.com/apples/grapes/rest/a/b

then I need to route the request to backend url: https://stores.com/a/g/caps/locks

I am able to achieve this by adding **<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Replace("rest/", ""))" />** to inbound policy

---

How do I achieve both the usecases in the same operation? as the response would be different for both cases;

I am unable to filter the incoming request based on context.api.path; when I send the request for first usecase I am getting 500: internal server error as apim is expecting uri path after rest/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862461/use-azure-api-management-as-a-passthrough

Comment: Why can't you define a second operation with uri-template of "a/b" and put in <rewrite-uri template="caps/lock" /> ?

Comment: They look better as 2 separate operations. Any reason why they must be 1 operation?